# Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket is masked

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

While trying to start gunicorn I get this error,

```
Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket is masked.
```

How do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can unmask the unit with the following command:

```
systemctl unmask gunicorn.socket
```

That will allow you to start the unit again.

A masked unit is an unit that has been prevented from starting. From the [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-enabled%20UNIT%E2%80%A6):

> `masked`: Completely disabled, so that any start operation on it fails (permanently in `/etc/systemd/system/` or transiently in `/run/systemd/systemd/`).

There might be a reason why the unit was masked in your system (maybe you or another system administrator masked it before?) So consider that fact while you ponder whether unmasking it is the correct approach.

You can use [the `systemctl is-enabled` command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-enabled%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) to check whether a unit is masked (or, more generally, what the enablement state of the unit is.)